# iPhone 11 Blank Navigation Menu

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress, mobile, responsive

I have a fully-responsive website, but after the release of iPhone 11, I have tried visiting the site, but what I get is a blank navigation menu, on Chrome and Safari. On all other devices, the menu is displaying properly. On iPhone 11, the navigation items/links are completely blank. What might cause this problem?

The site is already tested on all other Android and Apple devices, the menu works properly.

Link to the website: https://cutting-hedge.com

Comment: It would be helpful to include minimum reproducible example. Until that the question is too broad.

Comment: How is the question too broad? The problem only occurs with iPhone 11. I have tried with media queries, to imitate the same exact height and width in pixels, and this was not the issue.

Comment: I kindly request that you read this page. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
It is not good to make other people guess what could go wrong, because we don't see what is this website or minimum webpage with same effect, or even any log output.

Comment: @MaxDrljic : please share you website url so we are able to check this.

Comment: @sangeeta I have added the website url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `mobmenu-content` style and element positioning.

It could be fixed with removing either `position: fixed` attribute or `overflow: auto`. Then the menu becomes visible on iOS 13 browsers.